# external usb HDD not recognized in Ubuntu 22.04 with kernel 5.15.0

Tags: usb, kernel, hard-drive

I searched everywhere, without finding a solution!

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad with ubuntu 22.04. I was using the hwe kernel (6.2.0), and my Toshiba usb external disk was recognized and mounted without any problem.

I had to go back to 5.15 generic kernel in order to get virtualbox working, and now the usb hdd isn't recognized. When I plug it I see in syslog:

```
Nov  6 09:16:21 paolo-Lenovo-ThinkBook-16p-Gen-2 kernel: [42028.932552] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 29 using xhci_hcd
Nov  6 09:16:21 paolo-Lenovo-ThinkBook-16p-Gen-2 kernel: [42028.952945] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/8, error -71
Nov  6 09:16:22 paolo-Lenovo-ThinkBook-16p-Gen-2 kernel: [42029.060321] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 29 using xhci_hcd
Nov  6 09:16:22 paolo-Lenovo-ThinkBook-16p-Gen-2 kernel: [42029.081418] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/8, error -71
Nov  6 09:16:22 paolo-Lenovo-ThinkBook-16p-Gen-2 kernel: [42029.392409] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 30 using xhci_hcd
Nov  6 09:16:22 paolo-Lenovo-ThinkBook-16p-Gen-2 kernel: [42029.413411] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/8, error -71
Nov  6 09:16:22 paolo-Lenovo-ThinkBook-16p-Gen-2 kernel: [42029.520336] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 30 using xhci_hcd
Nov  6 09:16:22 paolo-Lenovo-ThinkBook-16p-Gen-2 kernel: [42029.540993] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/8, error -71
Nov  6 09:16:22 paolo-Lenovo-ThinkBook-16p-Gen-2 kernel: [42029.656532] usb usb4-port2: attempt power cycle
Nov  6 09:16:23 paolo-Lenovo-ThinkBook-16p-Gen-2 kernel: [42030.584460] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 31 using xhci_hcd
Nov  6 09:16:23 paolo-Lenovo-ThinkBook-16p-Gen-2 kernel: [42030.604984] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/8, error -71
Nov  6 09:16:23 paolo-Lenovo-ThinkBook-16p-Gen-2 kernel: [42030.712289] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 31 using xhci_hcd
Nov  6 09:16:23 paolo-Lenovo-ThinkBook-16p-Gen-2 kernel: [42030.733207] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/8, error -71
Nov  6 09:16:24 paolo-Lenovo-ThinkBook-16p-Gen-2 kernel: [42031.044694] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 32 using xhci_hcd
Nov  6 09:16:24 paolo-Lenovo-ThinkBook-16p-Gen-2 kernel: [42031.064972] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/8, error -71
Nov  6 09:16:24 paolo-Lenovo-ThinkBook-16p-Gen-2 kernel: [42031.172750] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 32 using xhci_hcd
Nov  6 09:16:24 paolo-Lenovo-ThinkBook-16p-Gen-2 kernel: [42031.193395] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/8, error -71
Nov  6 09:16:24 paolo-Lenovo-ThinkBook-16p-Gen-2 kernel: [42031.308675] usb usb4-port2: unable to enumerate USB device


$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 5.15.0-90-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-069) (gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38) #100-Ubuntu SMP Mon Oct 30 14:09:25 UTC 2023
```

Is it a kernel bug?

Any hint?